# Vi: substitute -- how to define the searching object

Tags: vi, substitution

In my source code, it has the following for example:

```
menu = add_menu_item ((char **)HW_KIND, 21);
.
.
if(get_idx_by_str ((char **)HW_KIND, prev->column_section, 21, 0) < get_idx_by_str ((char **)HW_KIND, curr->column_section, 21, 0))
.
.
fprintf(fp, "# %d floor\n%d@%d\n\n", i, get_idx_by_str ((char **)HW_KIND, section->column_section, 21, 0), stop->stop_landing);
.
.
add_text_to_gtk_text_buffer (text_buffer, iter, NULL, -99, -99, "??????????Ե -- %s\n", HW_KIND[steel_col_data.sec_idx]);
```

I wanted to find all the sentences having exactly key `HW_KIND` then also `21` and then change `21` to `20`. For example, the first three sentences above match the searching condition but the last one above doesn't.

If in a terminal in Linux, `grep "\<HW_KIND\>" foo.c | grep 21` will find all occurrences. How to define the substitute command in **Vi** editor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}HW_KIND.\{-}\)21\(.\{-}\)/\120\2/gc
```

With `c` option, you can confirm each replacement.
Try the above regex and watch it replaces the text as you want.
It will replace 4 matches.

`\(` and `\)` for capturing group, and `\{-}` for non-greeding match.

Comment: Is it possible to know the occurrence of all `21` meeting the searching condition mentioned above not using `s` commander in Vi? Or use commander in Linux terminal? The grep commander I used in example only shows how many lines having the searching object.

Comment: You can just search with `/pattern`. If you just find matching pattern, you don't need capturing group, so `/.\{-}HW_KIND.\{-}21.\{-}` would be sufficient.

Comment: I know `/` in Vi for searching. I want to know the total number of pattern. If using `s`, it will report how many substitutions occur. But I don't want to do the real substitution and want to know the total. Maybe it has nothing to do with this question. I am not sure if I should raise up a new question.

Comment: Perhaps you want to check the following URL: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern

Comment: Thank you for the URl because I learn the option `n` in Vi. But it doesn't work. I mean if I use `s` commander, it will show 18 substitutions for example. If I change `s`to `n`, it will find 17 matches. The one missing is, e.g., the second sentence in my example: there are 2 matches in one line and it only counts once.

Comment: When I test `:%s/\(.\{-}HW_KIND.\{-}\)21\(.\{-}\)/\120\2/gn` to your example, vim says that `4 matches on 3 lines`, which is correct. I wonder if you didn't miss the `g` option. If it still doesn't work, can I access your file and test it directly?

Comment: Do you know `sed` or `awk` or any other commander to meet the goal mentioned? Sometimes I need it in shell script.

Comment: This can be another question. You'd better ask it in separated question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for both HW_KIND and 21, while keeping all that's in between. For this, you define a group using braces `\(` and `\)` in the search text, and then use this group in the substitute with `\1`.

```
:%s/\(HW_KIND.*\)21/\120/
```

Such substitution can also be made on command line using `sed`.

Comment: If there are more than one `HW_KIND...21` in one line, it only substitutes the last `21`.